# How can I initialize an "Eigen" - Matrix blockwise?

Tags: c++, eigen

Sorry for the subject - I wasn't able to create a better one...

What I mean is: I have a 2d-Vector a and a 3d-Vector b. When I initialize b, b(0,1) should be set to a and b(2) should be set to 1. This code works:

```
    const Vector2d a(1,2);
    Vector3d b( 0,0,1 );
    b.head<2>() = a;
```

But what I would rather have (among others because of the `const`):

```
    const Vector2d a(1,2);
    const Vector3d b( a, 1 );
```

This doesn't work. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Eigen to give a proper answer, but if nothing exists you can always write a lambda function that returns what you want and assign the result of that to a `const`.

Comment: I, otoh, am not really familiar with lambdas in C++. Used it only now or then. Could you give me an example for this solution, please?
(It would be purely academic, because the answer below already suits my needs...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the const you would do:

```
Vector3d b;
b << a, 1;
```

If you really want it to be const, then you can do:

```
const Vector3d b = (Vector3d() << a, 1).finished();
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly :) Yes, I like to use const where ever it is sane and possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you could do using a lambda (assuming there's not an easier way by using a constructor call):

```
auto generateB = [&]() -> Vector3d {
    Vector3d b(0, 0, 1);
    b.head<2>() = a;
    return b;
  };
```

And then you'd use it like this:

```
auto const actualB = generateB();
Vector3d const anotherB = generateB();
```